# Delete row doesn't delete specified rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have two identical excel sheets with the same columns but different values. I have them sorted by column 5. The values in this column are alpha numeric. While most of the values are equal, there are some values in one sheet that aren't in the other. In my code, when I change the cell range for the TPGPRIOR sheet to (i,1), the Script works and deletes every row in the sheet. This makes sense because the columns are different categories and will never be equal. However when I change that range to (i,5) in order to compare two of the same category, the script does nothing. The eventual goal is to have both sheets containing the same values in column 5. Is there any edit to my code that will solve this problem?

```
Dim objTPG, objTPG_PRIOR

Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL.Visible = True
objXL.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objEXPO = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(FinalExposure)

Const xlAscending = 1
Const xlYes = 1

Set objEXPOSHEET = objEXPO.Worksheets(1)
Set objRange = objEXPOSHEET.UsedRange
Set objRange2 = objEXPOSHEET.Range("I2:I9999")
objRange.Sort objRange2, xlAscending,,,,,, xlYes



Set objTPGPRIOR = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath & "TPG Prior.csv")
                                                                                                                'REMEMBER TO MAKE SHEETS RUN IN BACKGROUND
Set objTPGPRIORSHEET = objTPGPRIOR.Worksheets(1)
Set objRange = objTPGPRIORSHEET.UsedRange
Set objRange2 = objTPGPRIORSHEET.Range("E2:E9999")
objRange.Sort objRange2, xlAscending,,,,,, xlYes



Set objTPG = objXL.Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath & "TPG.csv")

Set objTPGSHEET = objTPG.Worksheets(1)
Set objRange = objTPGSHEET.UsedRange
Set objRange2 = objTPGSHEET.Range("E2:E9999")
objRange.Sort objRange2, xlAscending,,,,,, xlYes


i = 2

Do Until objTPG.Worksheets(1).Cells(i,1).Value = ""
If objTPG.Worksheets(1).Cells(i,5).Value <> objTPGPRIOR.Worksheets(1).Cells(i,5).Value
Then
Set objRange = objTPG.Worksheets(1).Cells(i,1).EntireRow
objRange.Delete
i = i - 1
End If
i = i + i
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a few things for you to consider. The first is simple, you wrote

```
i = i + i
```

Now, you probably meant `i = i + 1`, since I assume you want `2, 3, 4, 5, ...` not `2, 4, 8, 16, ...`.

The second thing to consider, is that you are only deleting a row from your objTPG sheet. This means that when it runs into a row that does not match, it will keep deleting from objTPG and checking against that same row in objTPGPRIOR until it finds a match or deletes everything below that. This may be the behavior that you want, but I thought I'd point it out just in case.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code a little...

and as AndASM pointed out you probably want `i = i +/- 1` instead of `i = i + i`

Give the below a try

```
Dim objRange as Range
Dim I as Long

For I = 2 To objTPGPRIOR.Worksheets(1).Range("E" & objTPGPRIOR.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set objRange = objTPG.Worksheets(1).Cells(I, 5)
    Do Until objRange.Value = objTPGPRIOR.Worksheets(1).Cells(I, 5).Value
        objRange.EntireRow.Delete
        Set objRange = objTPG.Worksheets(1).Cells(I, 5)
        If objTPG.Worksheets(1).Cells(objTPG.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row < I Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
Next
```

This will continue to delete rows until the cell in the same row column match your other sheet...  Should this value not exist, it will likely delete all your rows.  I added a little check to make sure this doesn't cause an endless loop.

If your positive these values do exist then it should work just fine...  If you want an alternative script that will first check if the value exists in a row below just leave me a comment and I'll whip something up :)

Comment: hm it is giving me an expected end error for the end of the first line of the code you gave...maybe the alternate one can give me some more luck? thanks for the response by the way

Comment: @RichEdwards By end of the first line are you talking about the 'For I = 2 To ...'?  How are you declaring objTPGPRIOR?  When I remove that object and just use 'Worksheets(1)' it works fine for me.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the code leading up to the delete statements. That portion simply sorts each worksheet. Ignore the final exposure/expo sheet.